# n m-faced dice, sum of squares of the probability of each outcome

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Roll $n$ dice each with $m$ faces. You will have a probability distribution of the outcome. How to express the sum of the squares of each probability in terms of $n$ and $m$. The number of outcomes is $\binom{n+m-1}{m-1}$. If we say there are $a_1$ dice land on F1(Face 1) $a_2$ dice land on F2 etc. The probability of such outcome is $\frac{n!}{a_1!a_2!...a_n!)m^n}$. 
Just to clarify: the question is how to express the sum of squares of the probability for each outcome in terms of $n$ and $m$.
My attempt for $m=2$, I have calculated it to be $\frac{\binom{2n}n}{2^n}$.
Maybe we can come up with just a claim and prove it by induction using $m=2$ as the base case. But not an expert in programming myself. It will be really helpful if someone can even generate some formula.

Comment: What have you tried already to solve this problem? Any answers will be more helpful to you if you describe your attempts and thoughts so far.

Comment: Off-topic English nitpicking lesson of the day: "dice" is already the plural (of "die")

Comment: The number of out come is (n+m-1)C((m-1).

Comment: It's not clear what an "outcome" is. Is it an element of $[m]^n$,   a multiset of cardinality $n$ on $[m]$, or a number between $n$ and $mn$?